# Nativescript Module.export/Function Is Not working

Tags: android, module, nativescript

I have been trying to pass a function from my view model to my Js controller.I have tried to export the my model view.In the View,I have tried to capture the view model.Nut I am getting this error:**Brand.Catagory Is Not a function.** My code looks like this:

**Brand_view_model:**

```
 function BrandViewModel(items) {

       function Catagory (brand){   

       var viewmodel = new Observable({

        brand: brand,

    });

     return viewmodel

     };
 }

module.exports = BrandViewModel;
```

**Js Controller:**

```
var BrandViewModel = require("../../shared/brand_view_model");
var Brand =  new BrandViewModel([]); 

exports.brand=function (args) {
    var item = args.object;
    var text = item.text;

   Brand.Catagory(text);

 frameModule.topmost().navigate("view/brand/brand");           

  }
```

**View:**

```
     <Page loaded="loaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <ListView items="{{ categoryList }}" >
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <Label text="{{ category }}" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" tap="brand" />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are creating your view-model is causing this misbehaviour.
The easiest way to follow the proper way to create functions that can be accessible through your view-model is to create the base hello-world app.
Here is the generated code in the **main-view-model.js**

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function getMessage(counter) {
    if (counter <= 0) {
        return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
    } else {
        return counter + " taps left";
    }
}

function createViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.counter = 42;
    viewModel.message = getMessage(viewModel.counter);

    viewModel.onTap = function() {
        this.counter--;
        this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));
    }

    return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

Note that you are creating your Observable (called viewModel) and then you are "attaching" the method you want to export through the view model with

```
viewModel.myFuncName = func() {};
```

In the generated code above the function that we will have access to is called **onTap**  (getMessage is not exposed - it is visible only within the model file)